# Control another application Service

Tags: android, service

I have application A and B. A contains a `Service` which can be started from B.

I know how to start it but how do I send a message/Intent from B to a running (background) service that belongs to A?

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745779/binding-to-a-service-from-another-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I send a message/Intent from B to a running (background) service that belongs to A?

You can do it the same way: call `startService()`. `startService()` will start the service only if needed, but it always calls `onStartCommand()`, delivering to you your supplied `Intent`. This works both ways: A starting a service on B, B starting a service on A.

Alternative approaches include:

- Pass a `PendingIntent` from A to B, and have B use the `PendingIntent` to communicate back to A, either calling `startService()` on A's service or sending a broadcast to a dynamically-registered `BroadcastReceiver` set up by A's service
- Pass a `Messenger` from A to B, and have B use the `Messenger` to send `Message` objects back to a `Handler` on A (though this would require a `HandlerThread` in A's service, most likely)
- Have B bind to A's service, where A exports the service and offers an AIDL-defined binding

Comment: about `PendingIntent`, do you by any chance know what is `code` in `PendingIntent#send(int code)`? i tried to find out when / where i can access it but failed...

Comment: @pskink: I have never used that. If I had to guess, it's the result code passed to `onActivityResult()`, if this `PendingIntent` was created using `createPendingResult()` on `Activity`. That, in turn, is based on `setResult()` on `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: thank you, i'll check it, however i have a strong feeling that it should be accessed uniformly in activity/receiver/service...

Comment: seems it is only valid for `getBroadcast`, in the `BroadcastReceiver#onReceive` the `code` can be obtained by calling `getResultCode()`, still for activity / service i have no green idea: `PendingIntent#send` works ok but the `code` is like `Unobtainium` ;-)