# How to expose component from installed app to be visible to instant app?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

From the [developer document of Instant Apps](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/faqs.html)

> Installed apps can make themselves available to interact with instant through explicit intents.

And later, it is mentioned that instant apps cannot

> Discover the list of installed apps on the device, **unless the installed apps have made themselves discoverable to instant apps**.

But I can't find the details about how to expose the component of an installed app or any part of an app, for that matter, to be visible (and accessible) by instant app. And any limitation on that? (supported component types and etc.)

Comment: Let me try to understand here. You want your instant-app to be able to open another app, for example: an action in your instant-app leads to opening Youtube?

Comment: I want my instant-app to bind to a service exposed by another locally installed app.

Comment: Is it not similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745779/binding-to-a-service-from-another-app ?

Comment: No, it is not similar...Instant Apps are a new thing. Read about them: https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/index.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At last, I figured out the syntax:

For ***[Android O+](https://source.android.com/compatibility/8.0/android-8.0-cdd#3_15_instant_apps)***, you can specify `android:visibleToInstantApps="true"` to the component.

For lower version of Android, add this meta-data to your `<application>` (not working for components):

`<meta-data android:name="instantapps.clients.allowed" android:value="true" />`

More Info can be found here [**3.15. Instant Apps**](https://source.android.com/compatibility/8.0/android-8.0-cdd#3_15_instant_apps)

Comment: example can be look at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera2/+/master/AndroidManifest.xml and https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/ContactsProvider/+/master/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Saved my life. Thanks. Where did find the documentation for instaapps.clients.allowed meta-data? Googling seems to reveal exmaples but not the official doc from android...