# Call another app(process) service using messenger interface for IPC

Tags: android, android-intent, service, messenger

I am going through the following tutorial:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Messenger and also https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/android-bound-service-ipc-with-messenger-2/

to understand how we can comunicate with a service created by another app by using messenger system.

But I am unable to understand how we can call other apps service like this:

```
switch (respCode) {
    case ConvertService.TO_UPPER_CASE_RESPONSE: {
     result = msg.getData().getString("respData");
     txtResult.setText(result);
    }
   }
```

Here convertservice is the service which they have used in the tutorial. But how can I access the static variable of the other app service.. ?? Or How can I call it over IPC. Because it feels like they created a local service and called it.. sorry about this but I am not able to understand this.

Comment: I used this [android- Binding from another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745779/binding-to-a-service-from-another-app) for the solution. It worked.